# Issue with TOPN and SUMMARIZE in Dax

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to find the top 5 items sales based on the turnover but I keep receiving this error : The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value.

```
Top_Five_Items_Turnover = 
VAR X = 
   CALCULATE( 
    TOPN(
        5,
        SUMMARIZE(
            Sales,
            Sales[item],
            "Top_Five",
            Sales[item]
        ),
        [Turnover], DESC
    ),
    Sales[item]
   )
RETURN
X
```

Comment: Your second reference to `Sales[item]` within `SUMMARIZE` should be the expression you wish to calculate for each `Sales[item]`. You are attempting to pass a reference to that field without any aggregating function, which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you cannot return a entire table using a measure. instead return values.

```
Top 5 =
VAR totalSales =
    SUM ( Sales[item] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        totalSales,
        FILTER (
            VALUES ( Sales[item] ),
            IF (
                RANKX ( ALL ( Sales[item]), [Turnover], desc) <= 5,
                [Total Sales],
                BLANK ()
            )
        )
    )
```